# Нарезка psd макета сайтов

Tags: вёрстка

Стоит задача нарезать и сверстать psd макеты страниц сайта и в каждом макете много разных не повторяющихся элементов. Как лучше нарезать когда я приступаю к следующей странице, последовательно, или лучше нарезать все, и тогда верстать? Как это делаете вы?

Comment: Обычно сначала нарезается каркас, который одинаковый на всех страницах. Потом уже на этот каркас и навешиваются детали. А вы наоборот чтоль хотели? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После просмотра макета в голове уже должно появиться понятие какая будет разметка примерно, что будет на фоне что прозрачное.

Если все вырезать сразу - сделаете быстрее, т.к. каждый раз лазить в фотошоп и по одной иконке резать затратно по времени (о цветами и шрифтами все равно придется). Но такой способ применим если опыта много и все помните хорошо ).

Если только начинаете - резать по одной картинке и в обнимку с "пипеткой" фотошоповской не спеша верстать :).

> Как это делаете вы?

Я делаю так:

Смотрю на похожие элементы (блоки, иконки, кнопки и т.д.) и пишу универсальные стили которые будут повторяться (посмотрите на [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)). Если надо, создаю спрайты, для иконок например [Статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/159027/).

Потом начинаю верстать и режу походу дела (иногда режу сразу, а потом верстаю, но не часто).

Не забываем что все страницы сайта "тянут" тот же css файл, потому код пишем более-менее универсальный, а не для каждой страницы свой (это еще и от дизайна зависит правда).

Answer (score 2):

Лично я сначала подготавливаю html, а потом в ходе написания стилей начинаю параллельно вырезать. вам необходимо подобрать свой стиль написания попробуйте так и так и посмотрите какой для вас более удобен.